# Condition for functional series to be not uniformly convergent

Tags: uniform-convergence

Let $\{x_n\} \in X$ be a sequence such that series $\sum_n f_n(x_n)$ diverges.

In general, this condition does not imply that series $\sum_n f_n(x)$is not uniformly convergent on $X$.

But are there some conditions to sequence, X or series such that this condition imply lack of uniform convergence of series?

Comment: I mean, there are several obstruction to such a test, namely most of the ones where $\sum_n f_n$ converges uniformly to a non-zero function.

Comment: If $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence (eg X sequentially compact) we cannot have uniform convergence

Comment: I am confused. What is the $x$ in $\sum_n f_n(x)$, and its relation to the sequence $x_n$?

Comment: Here $x$ is a variable.